# Unknown variable floor_tex on Gamemaker 8.1. How to fix it?

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-language

I have a very trouble with Gamemaker 8.1.

So recently, I've followed this video tutorial which shows creating a game 3D on its game engine.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Jo0JEEukhc

I tried to test my game, but an error message shows
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwBdm.png)
What caused that error? Here is the code so I hope you can fix it as well.

```
direction -= (display_mouse_get_x() -(display_get_width()/2))/5
zto -= (display_mouse_get_y() -(display_get_height()/2))/2
display_mouse_set(display_get_width()/2,display_get_height()/2)

xto = lengthdir_x(100,direction)+x
yto = lengthdir_y(100,direction)+y

d3d_set_projection(x,y,z,xto,yto,zto,0,0,1)

draw_set_color(c_white)
d3d_draw_floor(0,0,0,room_width,room_height,0,background_get_texture(floor_tex),room_width/128,room_height/128)
d3d_draw_floor(0,0,100,room_width,room_height,100,background_get_texture(root_tex),room_width/128,room_height/128)
```

Also, the version of Gamemaker is 8.1.141 (r11549)

Thanks
Cheers
-Sajad Sadiq Abd Amhamad

Answer (score 0):

In the video, the author creates two Background resources around 0:25, called `floor_tex` and `roof_tex` (mistyped as `root_tex` in your code). You'd want to either name your resources accordingly or adjust your code to match the names in your project.